# MEF modules not loaded or error on trying to "force" load

Tags: c#, prism, mef

How does the "ConfigureAggregateCatalog" differ from "ConfigureModuleCatalog"?
The prism 5.0 quickstart example on mef shows 3 ways of loading modules: from assembly catalog, from directory catalog, and from a config file. Looks like the `AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(...))` is enough to find and load modules. Without the ConfigureModuleCatalog's `ModuleCatalog.Add(new ModuleInfo(...)` I am not even able to get any error; the module is not loaded.

I get the following exception when loading the module in the way shown below.

An unhandled exception of type  'Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.ModuleTypeLoadingException' occurred in Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Composition.dll

Additional information: Failed to load type for module ExportBuildPreferencesModule.

Error was: Unable to locate the module with type 'FourZero.ExportBuild.Preferences.ExportBuildPreferencesModule, FourZero.ExportBuild.Preferences, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' among the exported modules. Make sure the module name in the module catalog matches that specified on ModuleExportAttribute for the module type..`

If I remove the ConfigureModuleCatalog method, I get: `Additional information: Module ExportBuildPreferencesModule was not found in the catalog.`

```
public class BootStrapper : MefBootstrapper
{
    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return this.Container.GetExportedValue<MainWindow>("MainWindow");
    }

    protected override void InitializeModules()
      {
          this.ModuleCatalog.Initialize();
      }

    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        base.InitializeShell();
        Application.Current.MainWindow = (Window)this.Shell;
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
        this.moduleManager = this.Container.GetExportedValue<IModuleManager>();
        this.moduleManager.LoadModule("ExportBuildPreferencesModule");
        //this.moduleManager;
    }

    private IModuleManager moduleManager;

    protected override void ConfigureAggregateCatalog()
    {
        base.ConfigureAggregateCatalog();
        //get the exported Shell from the assembly containing the bootstrapper (this) (MainWindow)
        this.AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(BootStrapper).Assembly));


        //get the exports from the Preferences assembly
        this.AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(ExportBuildPreferencesModule).Assembly));
    }


    protected override void ConfigureModuleCatalog()
    {

         base.ConfigureModuleCatalog();
         string path = @"G:\ExportBuild\FourZero.ExportBuild\FourZero.ExportBuild.Main\bin\Debug\FourZero.ExportBuild.Preferences.dll";
         Type modulePreferencesType = typeof (ExportBuildPreferencesModule);
         this.ModuleCatalog.AddModule(new ModuleInfo()
                                     {
                                         ModuleName   = modulePreferencesType.Name,
                                         ModuleType = modulePreferencesType.AssemblyQualifiedName,
                                         Ref = new Uri(path, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute).AbsoluteUri,
                                         InitializationMode = InitializationMode.WhenAvailable

                                     });            
    }
}
```

Following is the class that exports the module. Changing to `[ModuleExport("ExportBuildPreferenceModule", typeof(ExportBuildPreferencesModule))]` gives the same error.

```
[ModuleExport( typeof(ExportBuildPreferencesModule))]
public class ExportBuildPreferencesModule : IModule
{
    //[Import(AllowRecomposition = false)] 
    private readonly IRegionManager _regionManager;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public ExportBuildPreferencesModule(IRegionManager inRegionManager)
    {
        this._regionManager = inRegionManager;
    }

    [Import]
    private ExportBuildPreferencesView _exportBuildPreferencesView;
    public void Initialize()
    {
         this._regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.ExportBuildPreferencesRegion,
         typeof (ExportBuildPreferencesView));
    }
}
```